# uname returns host-kernel in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, wsl2

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 inside Windows WSL 2. When I run `uname -r` it says `5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2`, which is understandable. However, when I build a Docker image using the official Ubuntu image and then run `uname -r` inside the container created from that image, it still says `5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2`. This also happens when I use other Linux images (tested with Debian).

How is there a WSL kernel running within the Docker container? I don't have a "real" Linux computer on hand, so I don't know what the command should say, but I imagine it wouldn't mention WSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reasonable to expect that the Docker container would be running a different kernel *if* you are thinking about Docker as some sort of "virtual machine" technology, which it really isn't.

The "container" part of Docker is that it is being created *within* the Linux host instance.  That's what gives it its millisecond startup time.  Docker (and other similar technologies) are built using existing kernel features such as LXC, chroot, cgroups, and others.

If your Docker host was a "real" Linux instance, the container would also always show the same kernel as the host's with a `uname -r`.

Search for something like *docker chroot* or *docker lxc* for more information on the internals.

And yet there's still virtualization going on with WSL.  Before WSL (and still as an alternative), Docker on Windows did use a Virtual Machine for the Linux instance.  Then the container ran inside that VM, using its kernel and sharing its resources.  But now, with WSL2, its kernel can be utilized.  Yes, still behind the scenes it's a Hyper-V VM (of sorts) that's running WSL2, but it's so much more streamlined and integrated with the Windows host now.